# How to know that the container is up and running (Dockerode)?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

I am running docker using dockerode's `run` command.

```
    let dockerEvent = docker.run('imageName', [], process.stdout, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error while starting docker", err);
    }
});
```

I need to do something once the docker container is running.
How do I know when the docker container is running using dockerode library?

Comment: If you weren't using Docker and instead used, say, `child_process.exec()`, how would you tell if the subprocess was running?  Can you do the same thing with Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze Possible through the exit code "docker run" retuns. docker provides a web api/unix socket, where you can listen for events via `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/events` https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/SystemEvents Should not be hard do adopt that into node.js and listen for specific events (The curl example was for test, run it and start a new container and see what it logs) or with "dockerode" -> `docker.getEvents(options)`